# using hyper-v parent partition for a workstation

Tags: hyper-v, passthrough

I am setting up a Windows Server 2012 with hyper-v that will be used for running 3-5 virtual machines. The server has two pci GPUs and since hyper-v does not enable GPU passthrough I was thinking of using one gpu in the parent partition and one for remoteFX.

Since the parent has direct access to the hardware I could use the GPU for graphic demanding apps (for development). But that would require to install apps inside the parent partition. Is this a bad idea? Should I instead create a separate VM and access to it from the parent using RDP?

Comment: Possibly a silly question, is Windows 8 or 10 an option?

Comment: Windows 8/10 does not support remoteFX :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be technically pedantic, one *should not* run any more code than is strictly necessary on a Hyper-V host. It adds attack surface to the hypervisor and unfairly steals CPU cycles from the virtual machines running on that hypervisor.

But if this is non-production... just for development purposes... then do what you want.

(PS - I *think* Hyper-V in Windows Server 2016 has PCI(e) pass-through capability so you could hypothetically pass your GPU through directly to a VM... but don't quote me on that.)

Comment: yes, 2016 has DDA, but it is still a techical preview